# Longitudinal sorting of point cloud data based on custom made trajectory (C#)

Tags: c#, sorting, geospatial, point-clouds, lidar

Say I have a point cloud, represented as a randomly ordered List of Vector3s.  There is no other per-point information.

I also have a custom made trajectory (sequential ordered List of Vector3s) that was not recorded with the point cloud but manually created.

Is there a known way to order the point cloud based on it's minimal longitudinal relationship to the points in the trajectory.

I can't think of a nicer way to word the question so I will post a picture in an attempt to explain.
In the images, the grey boxes with numbers represent the index of a point at that location.

The first image shows randomly ordered points.
The second image shows the manually created trajectory (red line) and the orange lines represent the longitudinal relationship between the point cloud points and the trajectory.  You will see in the second image that the points are reordered based on that relationship.

[image]

Comment: You could use haversine formula to determine distance to each point in set, to each point in your vector. Then you can simply sort by shortest distance and remove matched points from working set. Ive always used this site for reference: https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html but many c# implementations exist. Its fast and accurate enough to process several thousand points on a relatively powerful machine without problems.